# How to make a Laravel pusher notification to display in background?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I have an application written in Laravel and pusher, my notification works very fine but I want it to work when browser is closed so that user can receive notifications even when browser is not open.

Below is the code i am trying to register a service worker but it is not working.

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('service-worker.js')
        .then(reg=>console.log('Service Worker: Registered'))
        .catch(err=> console.log(`Service Worker : Error: ${err}`));
    })
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: You are adding an event listener in the window object. I don't think you can listen even after all windows are closed i.e. browser is closed.

Comment: what do i do to get it to work??